# Emacs error cannot load file counsel

Tags: package, error

I'm getting this error whenever I try to open `Emacs`:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-missing "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "counsel")
  require(counsel)
  ivy-rich-set-display-transformer(backup)
  ivy-rich-mode(1)
  (condition-case err (ivy-rich-mode 1) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning13 :init err)))
  (progn (condition-case err (ivy-rich-mode 1) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning13 :init err))) (if (not (require 'ivy-rich nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" 'ivy-rich) :error)))
  (lambda nil (progn (condition-case err (ivy-rich-mode 1) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning13 :init err))) (if (not (require 'ivy-rich nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" 'ivy-rich) :error))))()
  eval-after-load(ivy (lambda nil (progn (condition-case err (ivy-rich-mode 1) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning13 :init err))) (if (not (require 'ivy-rich nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" 'ivy-rich) :error)))))
  (condition-case err (eval-after-load 'ivy #'(lambda nil (progn (condition-case err (ivy-rich-mode 1) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning13 :init err))) (if (not (require ... nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" ...) :error))))) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning13 :catch err)))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/apoorv/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 10649
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/apoorv/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/apoorv/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/home/apoorv/.emacs.d/init" noerror nomessage)
  startup--load-user-init-file(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1579fa7368c5>) #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1579fa731b9d>) t)
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

I have my configuration as a `org` document, this the block that installs `counsel`,

```
  (use-package counsel
    :init
    :bind (("M-x" . counsel-M-x)
           ("C-x b" . counsel-ibuffer)
           ("C-x C-f" . counsel-find-file)
           ("C-M-j" . 'counsel-switch-buffer)
           :map minibuffer-local-map
           ("C-r" . 'counsel-minibuffer-history))
    :custom
    (counsel-linux-app-format-function #'counsel-linux-app-format-function-name-only)
    :config
    (counsel-mode 1)
    (setq ivy-initial-inputs-alist nil))  ;; Don't start searches with ^
```

I also tried installing `counsel` manually by `M-x package-install` but it didn't help either.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: I think you need a line `:ensure t` in that `use-package` stanza for it to install counsel.

Comment: I was installing `ivy` and `ivy-rich` also, and for `ivy-rich` I had a `:after ivy`. I changed it to `:after counsel` it seem to have fixed it. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend purging your elpa directory, and then restarting emacs:

```
$ cd ~/.emacs.d/elpa
$ rm -rf *
$ emacs
```