# ivy-rich-mode not loading automatically after Emacs restart

Tags: init-file, ivy

If after restarting Emacs I do `M-x ivy-rich-mode`, the minibuffer displays "ivy-rich-mode disabled." However, despite this message, the ivy-rich functionality, such as vertical completion, becomes accessible. And then it stays enabled if I do `M-x ivy-rich-mode` again. Why isn't vertical completion enabled from the start?

init.el:

```
(use-package ivy
  :ensure t
  :diminish (ivy-mode . "")
  :bind
  (:map ivy-mode-map
    ("C-'" . ivy-avy))
  :config
  (ivy-mode 1)
  ;; add ‘recentf-mode’ and bookmarks to ‘ivy-switch-buffer’.
  (setq ivy-use-virtual-buffers t)
  ;; number of result lines to display
  (setq ivy-height 10)
  ;; does not count candidates
  (setq ivy-count-format "")
  ;; no regexp by default
  (setq ivy-initial-inputs-alist nil)
  ;; configure regexp engine.
  (setq ivy-re-builders-alist
    ;; allow input not in order
    '((t . ivy--regex-ignore-order)))
  ;; Use vertical completion
  (setq ivy-format-function #'ivy-format-function-line)
  )

(use-package ivy-rich
  :after ivy
  :custom
  (ivy-virtual-abbreviate 'full)
  (ivy-rich-switch-buffer-align-virtual-buffer t)
  (ivy-rich-path-style 'abbrev)
  :config
  (ivy-set-display-transformer 'ivy-switch-buffer
                   'ivy-rich-switch-buffer-transformer)
  (setcdr (assq t ivy-format-functions-alist) #'ivy-format-function-line)
  (ivy-rich-mode 1)
  )

(provide 'init)
;;; init.el ends here
```

---

PS:

The [maintainer's basic usage](https://github.com/Yevgnen/ivy-rich) is :

```
(require 'ivy-rich)
(ivy-rich-mode 1)
```

PS2:

```
(trace-function 'ivy-rich-mode)
(use-package ivy rich
...)
```

```
$ emacs --debug-init
```

Comment: I don't know anything about `use-package` but it *sounds* like the `ivy-rich-mode` variable is being set without the function actually being called.  Try putting `(ivy-rich-mode 1)` at the end of your init file?

Answer (score 1):

If I use your config and trace calls to `ivy-rich-mode` I see nothing when starting Emacs, and the following after using `M-x ivy-rich-mode`:

```
======================================================================
1 -> (ivy-rich-mode 1)
1 <- ivy-rich-mode: t
======================================================================
1 -> (ivy-rich-mode toggle)
1 <- ivy-rich-mode: nil
```

This tells us that the call to `(ivy-rich-mode 1)` in your config is happening after the `ivy-rich` library is being loaded, but that the library is only being loaded on account of autoloading when you call `ivy-rich-mode` interactively.  So the autoloading triggers the call in your config, after which the interactive toggle happens (which is now switching it off rather than on).

I know nothing about `use-package` but you presumably want to tell it to load the package right away, and at present you're only telling it what to do *if* something loads it.

https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#notes-about-lazy-loading suggests that `:demand t` is the way to do that.

Comment: See `C-h f trace-function`

Comment: I jumped the gun saying it worked. I'll update if figure out. Perhaps this: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/64849/emacs-error-cannot-load-file-counsel

Comment: FWIW, my personal opinion is that `use-package` complicates things for anyone who doesn't have a strong understanding of what it will expand to.  It looks useful for organisation if you know what it does, but seems to add a layer of obfuscation otherwise (and inevitably limits the pool of people who can offer help to those who use it).  My suggestion would be to firstly get this *working* without using `use-package` (I would start with the maintainer's suggestion) and *then* look at porting that configuration to `use-package` syntax.